# How to build android studio project using TFS gradle build?

Tags: android, git, tfs, facebook-android-sdk

Recently our team has started to use **TFS** for both *Version Control*, *Build* and *Release cycle* (*C++* and *C#* projects) and i'm being pressuured to do the same regarding the **Android application** we are developing.

The andorid project is in a separate **Git repository** on TFS and I have already managed to link the *Release* with *Google play*. What I'm struggling with is the **gradle build**.

During the build, gradlew stops, failing to find **Google Repository**, **Android Support Repository** and **SDK Patch Applier v1**

[image: TFS Gradle build error]

But both **Google Repository** and **Android Support Repository** are installed within the **SDK** which is specified in **local.properties** file (*C://sdk*).

[image]

What am I missing? Is there any more documentation regarding gradle and TFS beside [this one](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/gradle)?

I'm using default gradle build definition:

[image]

Comment: Could you share your build definition?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will try the auto-download ASAP, in the meantime, I've added the build definition to the question.

Comment: Did you restart the build service/agent after install the SDK? Can you share the capabilities of the build agent?

Comment: When I used build with --info it turned out the problem was with the following package: `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2`. There has been an issue with this package https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212128 so I have decided to reinstall my sdk and update all my dependencies. The build is now working properly :)